# mailman: Auto-approve based on database

Tags: email, database, mailman

I have a website where users can register with an email address. Those addresses are stored in a database. Is it possible to automatically approve messages from addresses in that database even if they are not members of the list? The only possibility I found for mailman to auto-approve non-members is with `accept_these_nonmembers`. Can I somehow dynamically bind this to my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct bindings to databases in Mailman, but you may consider the other way around; there's a neat and often missed feature within Mailman that was inherited from old-school majordomo - `Approved:` header. When this header is present within the message and contains correct moderator password, such message would be processed immediately.

You can setup a list moderator password within Mailman, and then add `Approved: password` headers to incoming mail by some other means, i.e. a custom script, procmail, or even Postfix or Exim header manipulation based on database query **before** the message gets to Mailman itself.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for!